# Setting variables/dictionary keys in python for loop to load multiple dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble iterating through a for loop in Python with a dictionary, as I'm not quite familiar with the syntax.
Here is an approximation of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'q1':'q1data.xlsx','q2':'q2data.xlsx','q3':'q3data.xlsx'}
for name,link in data:
  name=pd.read_excel(link,sheet_name=0,header=0)
```

What I am hoping for here is to end up with three dataframes, q1, q2, and q3. I'm either getting an error that there are too many values to unpack, or I end up with a single dataframe called 'name' from the last item in my dictionary.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You should be getting an error on line 2 that q1, etc. are not defined, first of all.

Comment: good catch, fixed the dictionary so the keys are strings now

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to use `.items()` when iterating over dictionary key-value pairs. Without this, you iterate over the keys only, which means that you only have one value to unpack (one key at a time), as indicated by the error you mention.

```
data = {q1:'q1data.xlsx',q2:'q2data.xlsx',q3:'q3data.xlsx'}
for name, link in data.items():
    ...
```

2. You can't do this with variables in Python. I suggest to collect the DataFrames in a list and then to unpack them to a known number of variables:

```
files = ['q1data.xlsx', 'q2data.xlsx', 'q3data.xlsx']
q1, q2, q3 = [pd.read_excel(link, sheet_name=0, header=0)
              for link in files]
```

Better: In order not to make assumptions on the number of DataFrames and to keep everything flexible, store the DataFrames in a dictionary:

```
data = {'q1':'q1data.xlsx','q2':'q2data.xlsx','q3':'q3data.xlsx'}
dataframes = {name: pd.read_excel(link, sheet_name=0, header=0)
              for name, link in data.items()}
#use like
dataframes["q1"]
```